# Unit testing against production database or using repository layer in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, xunit

I would like to unit test my service layer methods in my project, and according to Microsoft, there are [several ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy) to do so. I found two of them to best the best for my project: [testing against production database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-with-the-database), and using a [repository layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database) to abstract EF Core statements.

Here is a sample of a method from my service layer:

```
public async Task<PostQueryDTO>  GetPostByIdAsync (Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   Post? post = await _dbSet
       .Include            (p => p.User)
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id, cancellationToken);

   if (post == null)
   {
       throw new PostNotFoundException();
   }

   return post.ToPostQueryDTO();
}
```

Now if I were to add a repository layer, I would have to do the following:

Create a method in the repository layer to handle EF Core:

```
public async Task<Post> GetPostByIdAsync (Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return _dbContext.Posts
                     .Include(p => p.User)
                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id, cancellationToken);
}
```

And my service layer method would change into:

```
public async Task<PostQueryDTO>  GetPostByIdAsync (Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Post? post = (await _postRepo.GetPostByIdAsync(id, cancellationToken)).toPostQueryDTO();

    if (post == null)
    {
        throw new PostNotFoundException();
    }

    return post.ToPostQueryDTO();
}
```

The benefit of this is that the new method would be easier to unit test since I can use something like Moq to moq the repository method, and EF Core is abstracted into another layer.

The downside is that I would have to create a new method in the repository layer for every method in the service layer, and testing insert methods which would be tricky.

Now for testing against production database, I would say that some of the pros, are the cons of adding a repository layer (i.e. it solves them). But would using a local copy of the database (in SSMS or Visual Studio) work as well, and are there any other cons? (maybe other than commands clashing and causing some tests to fail)

I would appreciate if you would tell me which would be more suitable in what situation and your experiences using them.

Comment: Hello, usually there are no corns described while you are connecting to the local database. However, it's stated that `"Avoid In-Memory Databases for Tests"`. There would be no issues or pitfalls if you follow the same in your scenario. You could follow a few more good practices explained in the [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices)